# 2017 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

Salesforce Stack Exchange is scheduled for [an election starting next week, January 16th](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/election/2). In connection with that election, we will be hosting a Q&A here for candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2434/2017-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, January 16th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 3:00 pm EST on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- At the end of the collection phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, containing (up to) 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

---

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 11):

- Are you currently employed by Salesforce? (Such as the Developer Evangelists)

We've previously had [@metadaddy](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/67/metadaddy) as a moderator who was at the time on the Salesforce Developer Evangelists team. I felt this was a large benefit to the SFSE community as a bridge into Salesforce. It's certainly not a requirement to being a moderator.

Answer (score 10):

- What voting practices would you encourage users to adopt?

This kind of dates back to [Why aren't people voting?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/450/102) and how to encourage a positive community through voting. How can we use our votes to encourage useful questions and answers?

Answer (score 8):

- How do you plan to manage the quality of new user posts?

We get a flood of new users each month, and in general that is a good thing! We want our community to grow. But the question quality is often quite poor, and there is a learning curve to adding valuable content on the Stack Exchange, with different subtleties for questions and answers.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 7):

- As a moderator, how can we help to increase the acceptance rate ?

being with the site for few years now, one thing I see different compared to salesforce developer forums or success community is a large percentage of our questions stays open without any accepted answers. how can moderators pitch in to help increase this and what considerations should be taken care in doing this ?

Answer (score 6):

- How would you encourage User participation off SFSE?

I haven't been fortunate to go to Dreamforce (yet!), but do attend the Salesforce World Tour in London and I've often seen posts around Dreamforce and other World Tour meetups which is great. How might a moderator go about encouraging people to engage outside of Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 6):

- How would you be managing the flag/action to be taken on the SFSE in parallel to your daily work?

As the site in continuously growing and everyday new users joining it. This would generate a lot of expected and unexpected posts to the site which require action by moderators. I would like the know response time to be taken by moderator to resolve those actions. Do you commit to allocate a time slot to investigate and resolve flags?